# can't access local host of rails on mac when run command rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm trying to start with ruby on rails. I just installed rials and ruby as on install rails
Then i starting to run the command rails server and this is the result that i got as mention in the picture.
I can't connect to the server on safari it's says safari can't connect to the server.

[image: result on terminal]

*Edit*

I didn't pay attention that i should type the command *rails new* then the project name

Comment: Did you create a new rails project by running `rails new some_project_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears when you're not in a rails application. It's assuming you want to create a new rails application (since you're not in one) and giving you instructions to do so.

`cd` into your rails application or create one using `rails new` if you don't have one yet.